# What kind of a hash file is this?

Tags: hash

I came across a hash file with a number of hashes. I would like to know what kind of hash this is in order for me to break it.

root:UvaOgTevr12gk:16365:0:88888:7:::

Any suggestions as to how one can break this would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: this is a *nix passwd file entry no?

Answer (score 0):

Fairly certain its DES as its 13 characters and that makes sense given its a *nix passwd file.  Take a look at : http://www.subhashdasyam.com/2012/03/how-to-identify-different-types-of.html#.WKHQePmLRhE